# How do I correctly use OBJECT_DEPENDS to specify a non-source dependency?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to make a target depend on a non-source file. I should be able to use [`OBJECT_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/OBJECT_DEPENDS.html) for this:

```
project(test)
set_source_files_properties(main.cpp OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/file.txt)
add_executable(Main main.cpp)
```

(Directory contains:)

```
CMakeLists.txt
file.txt
main.cpp
```

But this doesn't work - touching `file.txt` doesn't cause `Main` to recompile.

As described in [this unanswered mailing list question](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-April/028566.html), there are clunky workarounds for this using `add_custom_command`, but they shouldn't be necessary. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce with cmake 3.18.5

Comment: @StephenNewell this was on 3.16.3. I'll test again with the latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was misinterpreting the output, looking for a line explicitly saying `Dependee A is newer than depender B`, as there would be with source files. Touching the file does trigger a rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that your code works. I would guess that either you are not saving file.txt after you change it, OR you tried a bunch of things in your CMake and now your cache is messed up. In that case, just delete the build folder and rebuild.